# Google Appengine logging for golang

Tags: google-app-engine, logging

I keep seeing these errors in the stackdriver logs for a google appengine app written in go:

> 2017/11/05 23:30:38 internal.flushLog: Flush RPC: service bridge
>   returned HTTP 400 ("App Engine APIs over the Service Bridge are
>   disabled.\nIf they are required, enable them by setting the following
>   to your app.yaml:\n\nbeta_settings:\n  enable_app_engine_apis:
>   true\n")

Does anyone know the proper way to resolve this? I looked in the docs and the `enable_app_engine_apis` beta setting has been deprecated. The app does work but this continually clutters the logs.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I asked Google Cloud Support. They replied that there is no way to avoid outputting it to the error log, as it requires a fix on their end. They raised a github issue. Here is the link:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-sidecars-docker/issues/82

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Thanks for editing your answer to comply with the site rules. I would recommend you take the [Tour] and read the [answer] page in order to ensure future answers abide by the rules here.